# How do I get mouse cursor position behind a control?

Tags: position, mouse, firemonkey, c++builder

I am using C++Builder 10.3 and FMX.

There is a `TImage` control, on which multiple `TRectangle` controls are generated by some operation. The `TRectangle`s are filled with `claLightGray`.

To get the mouse cursor position, I am using the `OnMouseMove` event for the `TImage` control. The problem is that I cannot get the mouse cursor position when the mouse moves into a `TRectangle` control on the `TImage` control.

How can I get the mouse cursor position for the `TImage` when it is on a `TRectangle`? I hope `TRectangle` is transparent to `TImage` in terms of mouse cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by setting `HitTest = False` (it is `True` as default) on the rectangles.

Comment: Thia is better than the solution I was thinking of (catching `OnMouseMove` on the `TRectangle`s and mapping the coordinates to the `TImage`)